# Error with geolocation

Tags: java, android, geolocation

so I have my program running good without including geolocation but as soon as I add it it crashes. I believe it has to do with where I'm placing it but no matter where I place it I it crashes.

So my onCreate looks like:

```
package com.example.androidhive;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewSpotActivity extends Activity {
TextView txtName;
TextView txtLong;
TextView txtLat;
TextView txtPavement;
TextView txtTraffic;
TextView txtEnvironment;
EditText txtCreatedAt;
Button ButtonEdit;
Button ButtonGo;
GPSTracker gps;
String location=null;
private Geocoder gc;


String pid;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// single product url
private static final String url_detials = "http://108.57.202.101:8080/skate_connect/get_details.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_SPOT = "spots";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_LONG = "longitude";
private static final String TAG_LAT = "latitude";
private static final String TAG_PAVEMENT = "pavement";
private static final String TAG_TRAFFIC = "traffic";
private static final String TAG_ENVIRONMENT = "environment";
private JSONObject spot = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_spot);
    gc = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

    // save button
    ButtonGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);

    // getting product details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting product id (pid) from intent
    pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

    // Getting complete product details in background thread
    new GetSpotDetails().execute();

    List<Address> addresses;
    try {
        addresses = gc.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(spot.getString(TAG_LAT)), Double.parseDouble(spot.getString(TAG_LONG)), 1);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
    Address address = addresses.get(0);
    for (int x = 0; x < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); x++)
    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(x)).append("\n");
    location =sb.toString();
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void onClick(View v) {
      String tag = (String) v.getTag();

      switch (Integer.parseInt(tag)) {
        case 1:  // First button
            gps = new GPSTracker(ViewSpotActivity.this);
            double slat = gps.getLatitude();
            double slong = gps.getLongitude();
            double elong = 0;
            double elat = 0;
        try {
            elat = Double.parseDouble(spot.getString(TAG_LAT));
            elong = Double.parseDouble(spot.getString(TAG_LONG));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+slat+","+slong+"&daddr=" + elat + ","+ elong + ""));
                startActivity(intent);
          break;
      }
    }
    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
     * */
    class GetSpotDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewSpotActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Spot details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... String) {


            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                // Note that product details url will use GET request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_detials, "GET", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Single Spot Details", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully received product details
                    JSONArray spotObj = json
                            .getJSONArray(TAG_SPOT); // JSON Array

                    // get first product object from JSON Array
                    int value = Integer.parseInt(pid);
                     int n=0;
                     while(Integer.parseInt(spotObj.getJSONObject((n)).getString(TAG_PID))!=value){
                     n++;
                    }
                    spot = spotObj.getJSONObject((n));
                }else{
                    // product with pid not found
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return spot;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject spot) {
            if (spot != null) {
                setContentView(R.layout.view_spot);

                // product with this pid found
                // Edit Text
                txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputName);
                txtLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputLong);
                txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputLat);
                txtPavement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputPavement);
                txtTraffic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputTraffic);
                txtEnvironment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputEnvironment);
                //need to add rest...


                // display product data in EditText
                try {
                    //need to add rest...
                    txtName.setText("Spot Name: " + spot.getString(TAG_NAME));
                    txtLong.setText("Longitude: " + location);
                    txtLat.setText("Latitude: " + spot.getString(TAG_LAT));
                    txtPavement.setText("Pavement: " + spot.getString(TAG_PAVEMENT));
                    txtTraffic.setText("Traffic: " + spot.getString(TAG_TRAFFIC));
                    txtEnvironment.setText("Environment: " + spot.getString(TAG_ENVIRONMENT));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

}
Where spot.getString(TAG_LAT) and spot.getString(TAG_LONG) are determined by new GetSpotDetails().execute();. I can't figure out what would be causing the error.

My logcat looks like:

```
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860): Process: com.example.androidhive, PID: 12860
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.androidhive/com.example.androidhive.ViewSpotActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2116)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1411)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5083)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.location.GeocoderParams.<init>(GeocoderParams.java:50)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.location.Geocoder.<init>(Geocoder.java:83)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at com.example.androidhive.ViewSpotActivity.<init>(ViewSpotActivity.java:40)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1084)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2107)
01-20 11:47:03.607: E/AndroidRuntime(12860):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: What you have in this line of code -  com.example.androidhive.ViewSpotActivity.<init>(ViewSpotActivity.java:40) (line no 40) ?

Comment: Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

Comment: I tried declaring Geocoder gc; still on line 40 and then put gc= new Geocoder(this,getDefault()); in on create but still getting an error.

Comment: The code you posted does not contain the line you mentioned. Your application crashes due to the ViewSpotActivity class. Please look into it.

Comment: The ViewSpotActivity Class is the whole thing, which I added to the original post. It says line 86 still, which is

    addresses = gc.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(spot.getString(TAG_LAT)), Double.parseDouble(spot.getString(TAG_LONG)), 1);